# CSS3 Flexible Box Model and nested layouts

Tags: layout, css, nested

I've been playing a little bit with CSS3 flexible box model as described in this article: [CSS 3 Flexible Box Model](http://ajaxian.com/archives/css-3-flexible-box-model)

I am trying to create a simple vbox with a nested hbox, something like this:

```
<div class="vbox">
    <div>Header</div>
    <div class="hbox">
        <div>Section 1</div>
        <div>Section 2</div>
        <div>Section 3</div>
    </div>
    <div>Footer</div>
</div>
```

However the content of the hbox is being laid out vertically and not horizontally.  What am I doing wrong and how to do it correctly?  Thanks.

Comment: what's the css are you using?

Comment: The css is inside the article mentioned above (I didn't want to paste the whole thing here and just included the link to the article instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `display: box;` declaration in the `.hbox` rule gets overridden by the `display: block;` in the `.vbox > *` rule.  You have two options:

**1 Make the `display: box` override the more specific rules:**

```
.hbox {
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    display: -moz-box !important;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-align: stretch;
    display: box !important;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    box-align: stretch;
}
```

[Approach 1 working example here](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/flexbox-1.html), the main disadvantage of this approach is that you're messing with the default specificity rules of CSS which may cause confusion in other places.

**2 Remove `display: block` from the more specific rules:**

```
.vbox > * {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    box-flex: 0;
}
```

[Approach 2 working example here](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/flexbox-2.html), the main disadvantage of this approach is that you'll need all direct children of an `.hbox` or `.vbox` to be block level elements.

Comment: Thank you Robert, all make sense now.  I completely missed display:block in that css.

Comment: @IgorB Remember when someone's given the correct answer to one of your questions, click the big tick to accept it as the answer.  More people will answer your future questions if you have a history of accepting answers.